# How can I merge multiple bookmark (html format) files?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I am looking for a way to merge a bunch of different bookmark files without importing duplicates (or creating empty folders ... im looking at you firefox+bookmarkdd!).

I'm not looking to sync amongst browsers or computers, this is a one time merge of a bunch of different files.

Ideally I wouldn't have to install anything, as such I'd also be open to scripted solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Bookmark Merger](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bookmark-merger/files/bookmark-merger/0.1/bookmark-merger0.1.tar/download). It is a python module that will merge the `bookmarks.html` files generated by Firefox while removing duplicates.

Description:

> Bookmark Merger is a Python
>   library/module written mostly for the
>   purpose of merging multiple bookmark
>   files together. It works only with the
>   bookmark.html files created by
>   Firefox.

Comment: I'm accepting this since it got me close enough - thanks

Comment: Bookmark Manager does preserve tags with a few caveats according to this [discussion post on Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/p/bookmark-merger/discussion/general/thread/9195f779/#82a0/e1d4/b349)

Comment: Not only is it a library/module; but you can also down a standalone .exe (with its source files).  When you run it, it by default tries to merge all .html files in the current directory into a merged .html file.  Then, just delete all yer bookmarks in FF, and import the merged file.  To say so in as many words.

Answer (score 1):

So, you wish to merge multiple html files with possible duplicates without importing them in firefox ?

I'd say the easiest solution would be just that - import them in FF, get some extension to check for duplicates, delete those, and then export them again.

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/1553 one such addon, "Bookmark Duplicate Detector"

Comment: that would be the "bookmarkdd" he refers to in the question :P

Comment: Nope. I knew of some other one, but for the like of god, I can't remember the name now. Anyways, 'tis not important ...

Comment: As of today Bookmark Duplicate Detector has been updated the last time in 2009 and is not supported by Firefox 53. There are a few requests pending and asking to sync it, apparently unattended.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. In my opinion, the easiest way is:
Let's say you have 100 bookmarks in Mozilla and 4 more files with bookmarks in json/html format.
The idea is to have every file in html.

- So, export the ones in Mozilla to html.
- Delete them from Mozilla afterwards.
- Show all bookmarks -> Import and backup -> Restore -> Choose file -> choose one of the json ones you have (if you don t have any, skip this step).
- After that, export the newly acquired bookmarks to html and delete them from Mozilla.
- Repeat as many times as needed.

Now, you only have .html bookmarks, a few files. Make sure all the bookmarks from within Mozilla are deleted and start importing the html (Import bookmarks from HTML).
Do this for every html file, do not delete anything.

After that, simply arrange them, you will have multiple folders inside the bookmarks but it shouldn't take more than 5 minutes and manually delete the duplicates after sorting them by name.

And voilà, no software, no bookmarks lost, everything takes tops 15 minutes (and I had hundreds of bookmarks in 5 different html files).

Answer (score 1):

Some update. As of 2015, independant third-party bookmarks merger tools may still work. Though none of those I've checked and tested handle *tags* or *annotations* thanks to a Fx limitation.

Now Firefox finally supports export/import tags and annotations starting with version 43 ([my source and test](https://www.diigo.com/outliner/85adjv/Bookmarks-made-usable!-Sync%2C-merge-with-tags-and-more?key=lthwaiel2y). This allows to export/import any bookmarks' folder(s) you wanna keep, in place of replacing the whole lot, finally :)

Comment: Keeping tags is an important guarantee since a lot of work gets invested there. Upvote for bringing up this feature

Answer (score 0):

A tip is to use Firefox Portable for the merging, (install it to a folder on your desktop for easy access). Export all your bookmarks from your different browsers to html files. Then import all your exported bookmark files to FF Portable, edit them and save a new booksmarks file that you import to your main browser. [Firefox Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable)