# How to merge Bookmarks (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I merge multiple bookmark (html format) files?](https://superuser.com/questions/38711/how-can-i-merge-multiple-bookmark-html-format-files)

How can I best compare merge bookmarks (Firefox)?

(I can easily remove duplicates)

I am using XMarks, but somehow it cant merge.
I have tried to export and merge with Git, but what I see there doesn't make sense.

Comment: See

http://superuser.com/questions/38711/how-can-i-merge-multiple-bookmark-html-format-files

Answer (score 1):

I ended up importing and using duplicate detector.